# How to apply accessibility in MDHTMLLABEL Link?

Tags: xamarin.ios

- not applying the voiceover accessibility on MDHTMLLABEL HTML TEXT link in xamarin iOS
- i am doing below code:

```
lblSubHeading2.HtmlText = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString (
                    "EPMRoomParentMessageLine3",
                    null);
```

- i am using HTMLTEXT so i am not able to give accessibility on this text or link so give me solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to create bindings to `MDHTMLLABEL` library, then you can call the method from `MDHTMLLABEL` in your project.

Here is the document and samples you can refer: [Binding Objective-C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/?context=xamarin/ios) and [walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=windows).

Comment: Thanks but it not working because of i want to link and text in one label when i on accessibility at time when i move on link at time i want to know it is link so i can click .please any other solution

Comment: @kevinpatel Are you using MDHTMLLABEL library? What is `lblSubHeading2`, a label? While a label doesn't have a property called HtmlText.  You want to know if the text on the label is a link? And if it is a link, you want to make it clickable?

Comment: `MDHTMLLabel lblSubHeading2 = new MDHTMLLabel ();`
`lblSubHeading2.HtmlText = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString (`
     `"EPMRoomParentContactLine1",`
     `null);`

use above code but not give the accessibility MDHTMLLABEL if i give than not working accessibility so i want to work accessibility on that

**Localizable.strings**
`"EPMRoomParentContactLine1"="<a href=\"https://www.google.com\"><u>Invite other parents</u></a> to your personal connections to stay in touch with them long term";`

if i use accessibilty than not work on this so please give me suggestion

Comment: @kevinpatel Sorry, I don't understand you. I don't think you can use a MDHTMLLabel  directly in a Xamarin.iOS project. What do you mean by give the accessibility MDHTMLLABEL?

Comment: okay thank you @Jack Hua - MSFT can share contact to explain in details

Comment: I can't share contact, you can upload a demo with the problem to Github and then I can check it for you,

Comment: it working fine in normal mode but when i start voiceover mode i am not able to click on link @Jack Hua - MSFT